# Updating a view controller's content from another view controller without opening it

Tags: ios, swift

In the app I am developing I need to update 2 view controllers when a button is tapped. I managed to update the view controller which contain the button, but i could not update the content of the other view controller.

I tried to do so by a couple of ways: first, I created a delegate variable (using a protocol) in the view controller of the button and set its value to the other view controller:

```
var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegateForcast? = ViewController2()
```

as ViewController2 is the view controller I am trying to update using the delegate.

the protocol:

```
protocol WeatherServiceDelegateForcast{
    func SetForcast(forcast: ForcastInfo)
}
```

The SetForcast func in viewController2

```
func SetForcast(forcast: ForcastInfo) {
    self.day1Label.text = ....
}
```

the problem is that when executing the function SetForcast, the IBOutlet of day1label is nil and as a result it cannot be updated. I suppose that is happens because the view controller has not yet been loaded, but i could not figure out a way to load it.

secondly, I tried to use segue (without delegate) to pass the data to viewcontroller2. That worked but only when I used type show for the segue and in my app it is critical that it won't open. When i tried to use segue without opening viewcontroller2 (by type custom) it once again did not work and could not identify the IBOutlets.

Any suggestions how to pass the data to viewcontroller2 without opening it?

**edit:**

this is the code i used:

when the button in viewcontroller1 is tapped it takes the data from textfield and call the function from its property weather service (that works).

```
 self.weatherService.GetForcast(textField.text!)
```

GetWeather gets the weather of a city, creates a variable from type forecast and then:

```
if self.delegate2 != nil
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.delegate2?.SetForecast(forecast)
            })
        }
```

as delegate2 is the property of weatherService that refers to viewcontroller2 and this is how it is defined in the beginning of weatherService class:

```
var delegate2: WeatherServiceDelegateForecast? = ViewController2()
```

and WeatherServiceForcast is the protocol:

```
protocol WeatherServiceDelegateForcast
{
    func SetForecast(forecast: ForecastInfo)
}
```

then, according to the debugger, it executes SetForecast of viewcontroller2 with the right forecast variable:

```
func SetForcast(forcast: ForcastInfo) {
    self.day1 = String(round(forcast.day[0])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[0]))
    self.day2 = String(round(forcast.day[1])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[1]))
    self.day3 = String(round(forcast.day[2])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[2]))
    self.day4 = String(round(forcast.day[3])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[3]))
    self.day5 = String(round(forcast.day[4])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[4]))
    self.day6 = String(round(forcast.day[5])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[5]))
    self.day7 = String(round(forcast.day[6])) + "-" + String(round(forcast.night[6]))
}
```

as day1-7 are variables in viewController2 class from which i want to update the labels of viewController2 afterwards, and this is how these variables are defined:

```
var day1 = String()
var day2 = String()
var day3 = String()
var day4 = String()
var day5 = String()
var day6 = String()
var day7 = String()
```

in viewDidLoad i put the code to update the labels into the strings of the variables day1-7 but it seems it firstly calls that function and only then it calls set forecast and updates the variables.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.day1Label.text = self.day1
    self.day2Label.text = self.day2
    self.day3Label.text = self.day3
    self.day4Label.text = self.day4
    self.day5Label.text = self.day5
    self.day6Label.text = self.day6
    self.day7Label.text = self.day7

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not update the content of your `viewController2` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`? A view controller won't load its view and subviews until it needs to display them on screen.
 Therefore, Views of your `viewController2` is not loaded if you are not going to present it, that's why you got nil and you can't access it.

A clean way to achieve what you want is:

1. Have a separate property in `viewController2` to store the data
2. Set content of the property in `viewController1`
3. Then update the view of `viewController2` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` according to the property you just set.

**Edit**

Try change this:

```
if self.delegate2 != nil
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.delegate2?.SetForecast(forecast)
            })
        }
```

to

```
if self.delegate2 != nil
    {
        self.delegate2?.SetForecast(forecast)

    }
```

Code inside a async block will be executed asynchronously , so `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidload` may be called **before** these properties are set. 
That's why these values are "". Also, no need to use async block here, what you are doing in `SetForcast` is just set values of properties, they are finished almost immediately.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason in it firstly executes viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear - it updates the labels i need to the properties that  are still not updated and only then it puts the data i need in the properties but it is too late. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that both of these view controllers are in the same scroll view of another view controller? maybe that causes the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear to start too soon?

Comment: Could you add the code to your question? Then I can see if I can help you

Comment: I added the code that went wrong  in the edit, i would be very thankful if you could skim through it @luiyezheng

Comment: I now noticed that the app executes the code of viewDidLoad and ViewWillApear at the very beginning when the app starts and never executes it again, I think it means that the viewcontroller2 is loaded from the beginning but i still cannot update the content of view controller2 as the labels are nil when i try to update them so it's weird

Comment: One thing I notice is that you put the 'setForecast' in a async block, why did you do this?  If you put something in a async block, then it is supposed not to block the threads ,and viewWillAppear or viewDidload could be called before these properties are set.

Comment: You meant viewWillAppear or viewDidload could be called after these properties are set right? because that would be the only way to update the labels with the correct values from the variables. Anyway, after a lot of debugging i found out that after I set the right values to the variables in viewController2 (day1 - day7), when it tries to update the labels according to these variables it finds that they contain "" even though I saw in the debugging it did put the values. Can you think of a reason that would happen?

Comment: maybe I defined  the variables in a bad way? maybe it's because i call the function SetWeather from a different  class?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, what you wrote makes a lot of sense and I removed the dispatch function  but for some reason the problem persists. When i debugged it again, I found out that it does update the variables day1 - day7, when it performs viewDidLoad it treats it as if these variables are empty and then when i enter a different city, the debugger shows how it changes the last and correct values it set to day1-day7 (now it finds them) but once again, when viewDidLoad is called the variables are empty.

Comment: For some reason it treats the variables as if they are not the same in SetForcast and in ViewDidLoad but they are really the same. That is so weird and never happened to me

Comment: Ok I figured it out. The reason It treats these variables as if they are different is because they are. Instead of setting delegate2 to the existing viewcontroller2, I created a new object from this type by writing: 'var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegateForcast? = ViewController2()' so ViewDidLoad and SetForcast referred to 2 different objects

Comment: Thank you for your help!! The conversation here helped me to understand more about the problem so I could solve it

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this.

If the `ViewController2` is not loaded it won't **never** take the data.

You first have to initialize it, then you can give it the data, without *displaying* it.

You simply have to do an "alloc-init" to load it inside a variable. The you give the data.